# Desktop OIDC Spring application security: Configure client with initial tokens

Tags: spring-security

We have a Java Spring desktop application that we are now migrating into an OIDC security (with keycloak for now).
  For that we've **integrated a browser within the Java Application** to run the authentication and get the set of provided tokens (access, refresh, id).

Now we wanted to integrate these tokens with Spring security so that we can use a filter at our WebClient (which calls the server), and also that Spring could handle the access token refresh process.

We are trying to find the best approach to achieve this.

What we have so far is a solution for parsing the Access and Refresh Tokens to produce the Authorized Clients. In such cases we create the AuthorizedClientProvider as:

```
var authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
            .refreshToken()
            .provider(context -> {

                if (context.getAuthorizedClient() != null) {
                    return Mono.empty();
                }

                ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();

                TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> type = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {//
                };

                Map<String, Object> jsonMap = null;
                try {
                    jsonMap = objMapper.readValue(accessTokenValue, type);
                }
                catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                AccessTokenResponse parsedAccessToken = null;
                try {
                    parsedAccessToken = (AccessTokenResponse) TokenResponse.parse(new JSONObject(jsonMap));
                }
                catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                OAuth2AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = oauth2AccessTokenResponse(parsedAccessToken);

                return Mono.just(
                        new OAuth2AuthorizedClient(
                                context.getClientRegistration(),
                                context.getPrincipal().getName(),
                                accessTokenResponse.getAccessToken(),
                                accessTokenResponse.getRefreshToken()));
            })
            .build();
```

And then we create the WebClient filter as:

```
        String baseUrl = theOpts.getAuthServiceBaseUrl();
        if (baseUrl == null) {
            baseUrl = theOpts.getAuthServiceIssuerUrl();
        }

        clientRegistration = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(AUTHSERVICE_REGISTRATION_ID)
            .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.POST)
            .clientId("myClientId")
            .jwkSetUri(theAuthServiceIssuerUrl + OIDC_CERTS_ENDPOINT)
            .tokenUri(theAuthServiceIssuerUrl + OIDC_TOKEN_ENDPOINT)
            .build();

        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository inMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);

        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(inMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository);

        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                inMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository,
                authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauthFilter = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);

        oauthFilter.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        oauthFilter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(AUTHSERVICE_REGISTRATION_ID);
        return oauthFilter;
```

So despite this approach would allow us to maintain the access token (and refresh it) it doesn't quite allow us to create an Authentication for the application with these tokens (on a global strategy). I would expect to be able to use the ID token to produce it somehow.

We've seen that Spring internally creates an OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationToken when it receives the tokens at the login flow (which we don't use). 
This seems like the Authentication object we should create, but it requires to have the message exchange information inside which we don't have in our use case.
We can then see that this exchange object is used in more places of the Spring Security code, so we can't ignore it.

Also we've seen that at the InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService we have a method to associate an OAuth2AuthorizedClient with an Authentication object.
But we are not sure if this is the path, or what exactly needs to be done.

Would there be an appropriate Authentication object we should use to keep reference to the tokens (ec: the ID Token) on the application?

Does anyone knows how to configure / provide this to make this integrated browser solution work?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards

João

Comment: Just a heads up that the reactive OAuth 2.0 Client documentation is out-of-date and missing information. I would suggest looking at the Servlet docs as it's complete. For service accounts (client_credentials grant), here is the Servlet docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-client-creds-grant. NOTE: A client configured for the client_credentials grant will not receive a refresh token (not allowed per spec). However, when the access token expires, the client will automatically "renew" the expired access token by getting a new one.

Comment: Hi, 
Have read the documentation, but in no place it refers what to do when the Authorization code was executed outside (integrated browser) and we only have the tokens. 
On 12.2.4 it mentions the setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true) which would use the existent OAuth2AuthenticationToken. Is there any documentation on how to create it manually instead of running the HttpSecurity.oauth2Login()?

Without the default to true, on the UPDATE 2 we describe how we create an initial AuthorizedClient from the retrieved tokens and maintain the refreshToken. Not sure if its a correct approach.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "when the Authorization code was executed outside (integrated browser) and we only have the tokens"? This doesn't make sense to me? Also, this is not clear to me either "Is there any documentation on how to create it manually instead of running the HttpSecurity.oauth2Login()?". Create what manually? I'm confused because your original comment refers to service accounts, which is `client_credentials` grant and `HttpSecurity.oauth2Login()` is implemented using the `authorization_code` grant.

Comment: So I've tried to rephrase the entire question with the current knowledge and focused on the open points. 

@JoeGrandja, please check the 1st sentence. We have an integrated browser on this desktop application which performs the Authorized Code Flow and provides the tokens.

So we're trying to understand how to integrate those tokens with the Spring Security.
For now we've solved how to contact the server (and keep the tokens being refreshed), but not how to have a global Authentication object within our Desktop Spring application.

Hope this clarifies the entire thing

Comment: Can you put together a minimal sample -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - via a GitHub repository so I can see what you have. This will be the most effective method to help you with your next steps.

Comment: @JoeGrandja I've changed again the solution to use the Servlet Filter instead of the reactive one, and creating a copy of the OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken without the exchange object. The solution is able to parse the provided Token endpoint response to create the authentication, and uses Spring Security to keep it refreshed. Solution available here: https://github.com/joao-rebelo/DesktopSpringSecurity. Not sure if this is a correct solution or if it will bring problems that we are not seeing now.

Comment: the motivation for changing the reactive into a servlet filter was to be able to access the SecurityContextHolder on a Global mode. on a Swing / SWT application we don't have / need the reactive context.

Comment: I finally got around to looking at your sample but I can't run it without errors. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It should run without any errors and provide details on the issue you are trying to solve. However, looking at the code, there is a lot there that I suspect will cause issues down the road.

Comment: @JoeGrandja I've finally been able to put together a runnable example in a repository: https://github.com/joao-rebelo/oidc-desktop. You can check a more detailed description on my article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/oidc-desktop-jo%25C3%25A3o-rebelo/

Comment: Thanks @joão-rebelo. I've responded to the GitHub issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9504#issuecomment-803083180